# Fetch database data from firebase to my blog without auth

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've followed the guide from a documentation of firebase on how to fetch the data.

I try to play around with the:
[sample of firebase  here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js)

However, to get database data need to auth. Is there anyway just only fetch like feed from firebase without auth? I need to read on my own blog to be read for public.

Please..help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your rules to this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

But this means **anyone** who has access the database can read all the data.

In your code you would do something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("blogItems").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

If your setup is like this:

```
firebase-database-123
  |
  |_blogItems
      |
      |_entry1
      |
      |_entry2
```

Comment: @Imran Yes, on that database.

Comment: Well I'm stuck on main.js given in the sample

Comment: Do you have a simple sample page for that case?

Comment: @Imran Where is main.js?

Comment: quickstart-js-master\database\scripts\main.js

Comment: By the way...I'm still stuck on how get `firebase-database-123` if I don't know ?

Comment: Ok I got the answer. Thanks for your help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you get familiar with [Firebase Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).
These are the ones which dictate who can read/write into the Firebase Database.

All new projects starts with the rules

```
{
 rules: {
  .read: auth != null,
  .write: auth != null
 }
}
```

This means anyone who isn't authenticated won't be able to read or write in our database.

To achieve what you might need without compromising other data you may do something like the following:

```
{
 rules: {
  .read: auth != null,
  .write: auth != null

  blogEntries: {
   .read: true,
   .write: auth != null
  }
 }
}
```

By doing this you are allowing everyone to read the data inside blogEntries, and this means ALL the data inside, while if someone wants to write data to blogEntries they should be authenticated.

I recommend watching [The key to Firebase Security](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI) to further understand what can be achieved and how Security Rules work.

Comment: Do you have sample page for me to play round?

Comment: If you go to the database page of your project there is a tab called rules, there are the current rules and if you make changes they won't be public until you save them. There is also a simulator to simulate write or read.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the data without authenticating, but **it's not recommended**. I did the following setup in the Firebase.
**Step 1**
[image: Step 1]

Click on Realtime Database's **GET STARTED**

**Step 2**
[image: Step 2]

Click on second option start in test mode you can access data without auth

or
Add following lines in rules

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
  }
}
```